# MATLAB faster way to re-map indecies

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab, for-loop, matrix

Hi I am kind of new to Matlab and have a very naive implementation of remapping values in original matrix to a new points in another matrix.

I have matrix an Old_matrix(MxNxP) and i need to re-map every value of Old_matrix(m,n,p) to new_matrix (M, length(n)*sind(p)), length(n)*cosd(p)) .

The code I have so far is

```
% m,n,p are the dimensions of old_matrix.
% m = 560, n = 360, p = 45
% old_matrix is defined originally as 
old_matrix = randi(255,560,360,45);
% 

% 
new_matrix = zeros(560, 360, 360*cosd(45)+10);
for m_index = 1:560
    for n_index = 1:360
        for p_index = 1:45
            new_m = m_index;
            new_n = round(n_index*sind(p_index));
            new_p = round(n_index*cosd(p_index));
            if (new_n ==0)
                new_n = 1;
            end
            if (new_p ==0)
                new_p = 1;
            end
            new_matrix(new_m,new_n,new_p) = old_matrix (m_index,n_index,p_index);
        end
     end
 end
```

This is a slow process and I have additional code to make sure all new indices start at 1. Is there a faster way to do this, rather than go through every element using a for-loop?

Thank you

Edit: I forgot to mention, the size of new_matrix is initialized before the for-loops start.

Edit2: fixed the code so it works in matlab.

Edit 3: add images to demonstrate the transformation I am hoping to get. Image 1 has a starting matrix of 45 planes. Image 2 shows the volume from view(3) command. Image 3 shows the new_matrix's m-p side view.

[image: Starting matrix as a volume]

[image: Transformed matrix as a volume]

[image: Side view of new_matrix.]

Comment: This code is confusing. What are `m`, `n` and `p` beforehand? If they matter, does this code actually produce the correct result since it overwrites them with the loop indices? How are m,n,p and M,N,P related?

Comment: I have modified the code to make it less confusing. Sorry about that. Hopefully it's clear now.

Comment: you might try `reshape` - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html

Comment: @Dinesh, I thought about it initially, but doesn't reshape return a matrix that is the same size as input? In my case, old_matrix and new_matrix are not the same size.

Comment: Your code is broken, it tries to access index 0. Please provide valid code which runs with out errors. Include some example data for old_matrix like `rand(m,n,p)*255`

Comment: I have edited the code so it works in Matlab. Thank you

Comment: Now the code is without errors, but I don't understand it. Can you explain the `45*sind(360)+10`? Indices above 45 are never used.

Comment: Sorry, that line is a type. It should be 360*cosd(45)+10. The "+10" is to allow extra padding in the new matrix that will be used for interpolation between points. I've modified the code.

Comment: `n` remains same but in your description (new and old `n` remain at 560) , you want it to be changed to `ength(n)*sind(p)`. Why is it so?

Comment: That is because each p in my old_matrix represents an image of 560*360 that is retrieved from a scanner. I have to map each plane to a world co-ordinate system which is defined as new_matrix. I have added sample pictures in the original question to show the transformation I am hoping to get. Note that the transformation only occurs on two axis.